# Publishing getting failed on Deploying state

Tags: publishing, deployerservice

I don't know what I did wrong with my CD_Storage.config of Deployer, but it seems my publishing is not working anymore. I don't have a backup of the file, does anyone have any idea on that? It's failing on Deployment state stating the following error. Cd_core logs are empty for deployer. I see the following error on cd_Deployer.log file.

[image: error log]

[image: error modal]

Comment: Is it Web8 or early versions?

Answer (score 1):

As per your errors its clearly issue in your `cd_storage.config` you can do following steps:

DIY:

1. Compare with other environment's config
2. Browse to `resources\schemas\cd_storage_conf.xsd`from your installer folder & do XSD validation with your config file.

Paste your config after removing passwords in your question for further analysis

Answer (score 0):

If it's Web 8 and If you have added any deployer extensions, you might have made mistakes in adding the pipeline "**steps**". 
If not, look for the "`<Pipeline>`" configurations.. you might have doen typo in on of these. Check the reference file at - [here](https://gist.github.com/vikaskumar185/a63d334a95088d7c10b1b2987a1b8d1b).

The issue should be there, if not check if you have "`<Storage Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory" ....` " correct !